# Task manager does not open after deleting Process Explorer

Tags: windows-8, task-manager

I've installed Process explorer on my Windows 8 64 bit system. Few days later I have removed Process explorer again but the standard Task Manager won't open any more. How to fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have selected that *Process Explorer* should replace Taskmanager.

Delete the `taskmgr.exe` key in the registry under

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\`

Now You will be able to run Taskmanager again.

Comment: Nice answer. Good to know for when I go playing with my system :-)

Answer (score 3):

1) Go to start menu and open "regedit"

2) Go to:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution\taskmgr.exe\

3) Delete the value inside "Debugger"

NOTE: The "debugger" key open program that replace the default task manager"